# Abelian lie algebra homology

Tags: reference-request, group-cohomology, lie-algebra-cohomology

Let $\mathfrak g$ be an abelian Lie algebra over $\mathbb Z.$ We can consider its Lie-algebra homology, say as $\mathrm{Tor}^{U(\mathfrak g)}_*(\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z)$ and its group homology as $\mathrm{Tor}^{\mathbb Z[\mathfrak g]}_*(\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z).$ Is it true that these two functors coincide ? If so, I believe it should be known, maybe somebody know a reference?